# How to bypass a syntax error in a PHP script?

Tags: php, error-handling

On my WordPress blog, whenever I have a PHP error, it breaks the site and displays a white page with the PHP error.

For example:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in...

I can fix the error. However, I don't want users to see a broken site while I do. Is there a setting I can enable that will suppress the error (or more gracefully handle it) and continue to parse the rest of the PHP?

Comment: No, you cannot enabled relaxed parsing. Syntax errors are mostly fatal.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to correct the problem rather than attempt to ignore it?

Comment: Not trying to ignore it. Just need a bit more graceful warning than "Sorry, I'm stopping everything here!" This particular error was the presense of an extra semi-colon and its completely broken the site. I have to login via FTP to fix it. I was editing the script via WordPress.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you have a syntax error in a PHP page, it will always immediately stop parsing. It's the same thing as a compile error in languages such as C#, VB etc. There is no getting around this.

There are two ways you can suppress this error message. The first is with the `error_reporting` directive in your `php.ini` file. It's likely set to `E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED`. You can fine tune what is reported (via error logging and out to the display) by configuring the directives located on the [PHP Site](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php).

The other (simpler) way to suppress these is via the `display_errors` directive in your `php.ini` file. Simply set this to `Off` and restart your web server and you won't see these errors any longer - just a white page.

Comment: -1: Did you try suppressing a parse error with either approach, before posting this answer?

Comment: hiding errors doesn't fixes scripts. Now he'll be back complaining about "I have a blank page plz help wut can I do?"

Comment: @Damien: [Not even that](http://codepad.org/NBTO0wlo) (control [A](http://codepad.org/IDJEYtvl) and [B](http://codepad.org/o7DGE41e)).

Answer (score 5):

Sure: it's the setting whereby you **don't make a parse error in your script**. It's a setting in *you*.

<sup>(Parse errors generally can't be recovered from; what meaning does your script have if the parser cannot understand it? If it's not written in valid PHP? What do you want PHP to *do*?)</sup>

Answer (score -1):

**Since PHP 7** and for WP in particular I would suggest to put your your logical parts to separate files and then load them in try catch, because PHP **7** added the [`\Throwable`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.throwable.php) which can also catch `Error` including syntax errors when including file - ***but only from outside the script being included.***

So for example in your `functions.php` you will do `include/require/include_once/require_once` and put a logic in `yourTheme/your_script_with_syntax_errors.php`:

`functions.php` part will look like:

```
try {
    require_once __DIR__ . '/your_script_with_syntax_errors.php';
} catch (\Throwable $e) {
    // bypassed ...
    // you can put your error handling/logging here
}
echo "Script continues...";
```

Which in case of a syntax error in the included script will still result in something like:

```
...
Script continues...
```

So as you can see, even though there was a syntax error in the included file, the main script still continues...

If you don't want to use an existing logger, you can implement [custom error handler](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) and [`trigger_error`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trigger-error.php) in the catch.

```
set_error_handler(function (int $errno, string $errstr, string $errfile = ?, int $errline = ?, array $errcontext = ?) {
   // log something somewhere...
});
```

**Note** that **if you don't add** an error handler that doesn't print out the message, the **error will be output** based on your `error_reporting` level.